# Как получить значение из ответа?

Tags: jquery, json

Ajax запросом к странице получаю ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[<sub>Ссылка на картинку</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW7Dc.jpg)

Мне нужно получить значение из responseText, который имеет вид:

```
{
  'FACET_FILTER':false, 
  'PRICES':
    {
      'FULL_PRICE':
        {
          'ID':'15',
          'TITLE':'Цена',
          'SELECT':'PROPERTY_15',
          'CAN_VIEW':true,
        }
    }
}
```

Примерно такого типа. Как мне получить например ID?

Ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:"json",
  url: '?ajax=y&arrFilter_15_MIN=&arrFilter_15_MAX=13231&arrFilter_3_2212294583=Y&arrFilter_5_1842515611=Y&arrFilter_6_4088798008=Y',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: То, что у вас в ответе - невалидный JSON, собранный по видимому руками. Практически во всех серверных языках есть средства для сериализации данных в валидный JSON. Пользуйтесь ими.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:"json",
  url: '?ajax=y&arrFilter_15_MIN=&arrFilter_15_MAX=13231&arrFilter_3_2212294583=Y&arrFilter_5_1842515611=Y&arrFilter_6_4088798008=Y',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data.responseText.match(/'ID\':\'(.*?)\'/i)[1]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: @Oleksandr, обновил

Comment: @dakemu, Noooo, нормальный же был ответ. Только доступ к свойствам в javascript через `.`, а не через `->`

Comment: @vp_arth, там битый JSON, отказывается его парсить. Поэтому регуляркой пришлось.

Comment: @vp_arth, интересно, что за ответ такой странный выходит. Обычно работает, как в моём ответе

Comment: Всё, понял) там апострофы повсюду)

Comment: не знаю в чем проблема, но ответ такой же до сих пор со всеми вариантами (через точки и с регуляркой)...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:"json",
  url: '?ajax=y&arrFilter_15_MIN=&arrFilter_15_MAX=13231&arrFilter_3_2212294583=Y&arrFilter_5_1842515611=Y&arrFilter_6_4088798008=Y',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data['PRICES']['FULL_PRICE']['ID']);
  }
});
```

Comment: ответ тот же... обьект

Comment: @Oleksandr, я неправильно обратился. Изменил ответ

Comment: все так же получаю ответ как на скрине